# How Can I Setup a Google CloudSQL user that can connect only from App Engine Standard Environment

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I have a Java JSP application that uses JPA to connect to CloudSQL. The issue I am facing is that I am failing to setup a CloudSQL user that will be allowed access only from App Engine. Even after setting the user up to connect only via CloudSQL proxy it still fails. The user can only access the db when I put in the whitelist all IP.

Comment: Access is controlled by identity or IP address and NOT by the service type. Your objective of limiting access to only App Engine is not supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to get it working. The issue was that I was using the wrong jdbc driver. To enable my desired requirement I had to configure a cloudsqlproxy user and use the below connection string and driver to get it to work in App Engine:

```
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:google:mysql://instance-name/database"/>
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="user"/>
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver"/>
```

**NB:** The above only works after deployment to App Engine. You can use the standard non-Google jdbc driver to test on your local machine